# default value of dropdown on click of cancel button

Tags: angularjs

I have a drop down in a popup. I need to reset the value to empty when the cancel button is clicked.

```
<select class="defaultIc01Dropdown" ng-model="selectedTemplate"
        ng-options="x.templateName for x in listOfProductTemplates">
    <option></option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply set the `ng-model` back to its default state (probably `null`)

```
<button ng-click="selectedTemplate = null">Cancel</button>
```

Plunker ~ http://plnkr.co/edit/LeU7wwkVeAZFSvmxtqEz?p=preview